# odoo custom module installation ImportError: No module named examinations

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9

I created a super simple custom module on Odoo 9. But I can't install it, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 123, in load_module_graph
    load_openerp_module(package.name)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/modules/module.py", line 324, in load_openerp_module
    __import__('openerp.addons.' + module_name)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/modules/module.py", line 60, in load_module
    f, path, descr = imp.find_module(module_part, ad_paths)
ImportError: No module named examinations
```

Files:

**__init__.py**:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from . import models
```

and my manifest **__openerp__.py**:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
{
    'name': "examinations",

    'summary': """
        Short (1 phrase/line) summary of the module's purpose, used as
        subtitle on modules listing or apps.openerp.com""",

    'description': """
    Examinations Management Module
    """,

    'author': "My Company",
    'website': "http://www.yourcompany.com",

    'category': 'Education and Support',
    'version': '0.1',

    'depends': ['base'],

    'data': [
        'views/examinations_view.xml',
    ],

    'installable': True,
}
```

My module `examinations.py` is in models directory. Code is:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from openerp import models, fields, api

class Examinations(models.Model):
    _name = 'examinations.custom'

    name = fields.Char('Examination',required=True)
    subject = fields.Integer('Subject', required=True)
    exam_date = fields.Datetime('Date and Time of Date')
    exam_hall = fields.Char('Examination Hall')
    max_marks = fields.Integer('Maximum Marks')
```

I can't understant what's wrong. I created **init.py** file, manifest, model, view.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood something. When we say modules, we mean Python modules, and `examinations.py` you have there is not a module. A module is a folder with and `__init__.py` file in it. In the folder that contains your class Examinations, is there another `__init__.py` file that contains `from . import examinations` ?

Comment: @GeorgeDaramouskas: Python is happy to import a module from a single file; Python's standard library is full of examples. Is this a particular requirement of OpenERP?

Comment: Notre this: `__import__('openerp.addons.' + module_name)` — is your module under `openerp/addons` directory? I'd edit `/opt/odoo/openerp/modules/module.py`, line 60, and would print all relevant variables, along with `sys.path`, to have a better picture of what's going on.

Comment: Thank you guys. Yes, my fault was that I created only one init file in the main module directory. I needed to create another one in my module modules directory.